# Wanted but not invoked Mockito - Actually there were 0 interactions with this mock

Tags: junit, mockito

I tried the following still the same error:

I tried the following:

```
public interface InventorydetailQuery extends InventorydetailDAO {

    public static final String GET_UNFIT_UNSORTED_INVENTORYDETAIL = "Inventorydetail.getInventorydetailUnfitUnsorted";

    public static final String GET_UNASSIGNED_INVENTORYDETAIL_BY_DENOM_AND_SUBTYPE = "Inventorydetail.getUnassingedInventorydetailByDenomAndSubType";

    public static final String GET_UNASSIGNED_INVENTORYDETAIL_BY_REEL = "Inventorydetail.getUnassingedInventorydetailByReel";

    public static final String GET_UNFIT_INVENTORYDETAIL_BY_DENOM_AND_SUBTYPE = "Inventorydetail.getUnfitInventorydetailByDenomAndSubType";

    public List<Inventorydetail> getUnfitUnsortedInventorydetail(
            BigDecimal facevalue, String teamname, Integer fedofficekey);

    public List<Inventorydetail> getUnassingedInventorydetailByDenomAndSubType (BigDecimal facevalue, String inventorySubType, 
            String inventoryType, String valuableType, Integer fedTeamKey);


    public List<Inventorydetail> getUnfitInventorydetailByDenomAndSubType (BigDecimal facevalue, String inventorySubType, 
            String inventoryType, String valuableType, Integer fedTeamKey);



    public List<Inventorydetail> getUnassingedInventorydetailByReel (BigDecimal facevalue, String inventorySubType, 
            String inventoryType, String valuableType, Integer fedTeamKey, Integer bpsreelkey);

}


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {


    @Mock 
    private BPSReelQuery mockBPSReelQuery;

    @Mock
    private BpsreelDAOImpl reelDAO;

    @Mock 
    private InventorydetailQuery mockInventorydetailQuery;

    @Mock
    private InventorydetailDAO mockInventorydetailDAO;



    @Test
    public void testgetBPSReels(){
        when(mockBPSReelQuery.getBpsreelDetails(FED_TEAM_KEY, CURRENT_BUSINESS_DATE)).thenReturn(getBPSReelDetails());
        List<ShiftReelImportedBean> shiftReelImportedBean = processReelsAutomaticModeService.getBPSReelDetails(FED_TEAM_KEY);
        assertNotNull(shiftReelImportedBean);
        verify(mockBPSReelQuery).getBpsreelDetails(FED_TEAM_KEY, CURRENT_BUSINESS_DATE);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBalanceReel_Scenario1() {
        ReelBalanceBean reelBalanceBean = createReelBalanceBean(VerificationConstants.RS_NORMAL, VerificationConstants.RS_FINISHED);        
        CPFirstRunBean cpFirstRunBean=new CPFirstRunBean();
        RSNormalBean rsNormalBean=new RSNormalBean();       
        RecapBean recapBean = createRecapBean(BigDecimal.ZERO);

        Bpsreel bpsReel = createBpsReel();          
        when(mockBPSReelQuery.store(bpsReel)).thenReturn(bpsReel);  
        when(mockBPSReelQuery.findBpsreelByPrimaryKey(any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(bpsReel); 
        List<Inventorydetail> inventoryDetailsList = createInventoryDetailsList();

        when(mockInventorydetailQuery.getUnassingedInventorydetailByDenomAndSubType(reelBalanceBean.getFaceValue(), 
                        VerificationConstants.INVENTORY_SUB_TYPE_UNSORTED, VerificationConstants.INVENTORY_TYPE_UNSORTED, 
                        VerificationConstants.VALUABLE_TYPE_CURRENCY, FED_TEAM_KEY)).thenReturn(inventoryDetailsList);  
        verify(mockInventorydetailQuery).getUnassingedInventorydetailByDenomAndSubType(reelBalanceBean.getFaceValue(), 
                VerificationConstants.INVENTORY_SUB_TYPE_UNSORTED, VerificationConstants.INVENTORY_TYPE_UNSORTED, 
                VerificationConstants.VALUABLE_TYPE_CURRENCY, FED_TEAM_KEY);
    }
}
```

Still get the same exception.  Any tips in resolving this will be apreciated.

Thanks,

MS

Comment: Can you share your object under test?

Comment: I'd suggest declaring your object under test and tag it with @InjectMocks.

Comment: How can any of us possibly tell you why your test fails, if you (1) don't show us the code that you're trying to test, (2) don't show us how you're creating the object that you're trying to test, (3) don't show us the methods in your test class that actually interact with the object that you're testing, and (4) don't indicate which of your tests is actually failing?  This question is completely unanswerable until you actually show us the failing code.

Comment: Sorry, you're still not providing all the information we need to help you. Also, there's too much code. Simplify your question. In the process, you may even find the answer yourself. From what you've provided, there's no way to tell what your object under test is, let alone where in that object the problem may lie.

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough to answer definitively yet. Here's something akin to what I'd expect to see.

Reel.java:

```
package org.makeyourcase;

public interface Reel {
}
```

ReelQuery.java:

```
package org.makeyourcase;

public interface ReelQuery {
    void store(Reel reel);
}
```

ReelService.java:

```
package org.makeyourcase;

public class ReelService {

    private ReelQuery reelQuery;

    public void store(Reel reel) {
        reelQuery.store(reel);
    }
}
```

ReelQueryTest.java:

```
package org.makeyourcase;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ReelServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private ReelQuery mockReelQuery;
    @Mock
    private Reel mockReel;

    @InjectMocks
    private ReelService subject;

    @Test
    public void testThat_Store_DelegatesToQuery() throws Exception {
        subject.store(mockReel);
        verify(mockReelQuery).store(mockReel);
    }
}
```

Comment: If there's not enough information to answer the question, the accepted thing to do is to use comments to ask for the required information, and wait for OP to respond.  A non-answer is not an answer.

Comment: I did leave comments. Next time read the comments before suggesting that someone leave comments. :) The answer is to steer him in the right direction - a comment isn't enough to spell it all out, but can clarify exactly what he should be providing. If he were to provide sufficient additional information, I can easily edit the answer to zero in on what he needs. My goal is to be helpful to the guy. If you don't want to be helpful, the best thing to do is just ignore the question and move on.

Comment: @Don the above comments are probably put from the review queue.